# Finding Python dylib

Tags: mac, python, dll

This is a question that has to do with the way python is linked to a module in Mac OSX. I think someone in this community may be able to help.

I am working on Mac OSX High Sierra.

I am trying to use a python module which is linked to 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python`.
However, it cannot find this library as it does not exist.

My current python executable is 
`/Users/name.surname/anaconda3/bin/python`.

I tried to use install_name_tool to change the path to the current python one, but this didn't work and resulted in

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/name.surname/Desktop/picoflexx/libroyale-3.20.0.62-APPLE-x86-64Bit/python/_roypy.so, 2): Library not loaded: /Users/valerio.biscione/anaconda3/bin/python
 Referenced from: /Users/name.surname/Desktop/picoflexx/libroyale-3.20.0.62-APPLE-x86-64Bit/python//_roypy.so
 Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/name.surname/anaconda3/bin//python: not a dylib
    /Users/name.surname/anaconda3/bin/python3.6: not a dylib
    /Users/name.surname/anaconda3/bin/python: not a dylib
    /Users/name.surname/anaconda3/bin/python3.6: not a dylib
```

I think there must be some substantial difference between the framework version of python and the one installed by anaconda.

What I also tried is to reinstall python using

```
brew install python --framework
```

which installed python 3.7, the framework version. I then changed the library install_name to the new python3.7 framework path (the one just installed) and it obviously worked.

However, this is not satisfying: I normally use Python 3.6.5 and I don't seem to be able to find a python 3.6.5 framework version. Overall, my lack of understand of the difference between these two versions is preventing me to find the perfect solution, which is to bind my current anaconda version to the module.

So, the question(s) (they are all related I believe): this module is looking for a dylib called Python. Where is this dylib within the anaconda installation? Is it even there? If not, how do I get it? What is the difference between the anaconda version and the framework version of python?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See this previously posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51125013/how-can-i-install-a-previous-version-of-python-3-in-macos-using-homebrew/51125014#51125014) to get 3.6.5 on your system.

Since you mentioned anaconda, this might be more [appropriate](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/faq/#how-do-i-get-anaconda-with-python-3-5-or-3-6), which basically suggests issuing the following command, along with a more manual option:

```
conda install python=3.6
```